# Postgres: array_agg throws 'cannot accumulate empty arrays' for empty array(s)

Tags: sql, postgresql

Having problems when using `array_agg` when a row contains an empty array (`{}`).

This is my SQL query:

```
SELECT service_name, metric_name, array_agg(value_textarray)
FROM service_data
WHERE service_name = 'ActivityDataService'
GROUP BY service_name, metric_name
```

Where the column definitions are the following:

```
service_name - text
metric_name - text
value_textarray - text[]
```

When I execute the query and I have empty array (`{}`) in the database, I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  cannot accumulate empty arrays
```

How should I go about fixing this?

Comment: Simply add "and array <> empty" to the WHERE clause?

Comment: Indeed. `AND value_textarray <> '{}'` took the cake. Thanks.

Comment: Alternatively: `and coalesce(cardinality(value_textarray),0) = 0`

Answer (score 16):

I had the same issue where I couldn't filter the empty array and I found this function.
This function avoids the 'accumulating empty arrays' error.

```
CREATE AGGREGATE array_accum (anyarray)
(
    sfunc = array_cat,
    stype = anyarray,
    initcond = '{}'
);
```

source: https://gist.github.com/ryandotsmith/4602274

Comment: This works and can probably be customized to allow concatenation null arrays.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT service_name, metric_name, array_agg(value_textarray) filter(where value_textarray <> '{}')
FROM service_data
WHERE service_name = 'ActivityDataService'
GROUP BY service_name, metric_name
```

You also can add `filter(where value_textarray <> '{}')` right after `array_agg(value_textarray)`